# How can I execute a function every time fetch() is used in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, fetch, shared-worker

I am trying to post a message to my `sharedWorker` every time a HTTP request is made in my script to save me manually having to do it after every HTTP request.

I managed to get it working like so:

```
var App = {
    __webWorker: null,
    __XMLHttpRequest: XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open,
    __onScriptComplete: e       => {
        if( e.data.type && e.data.type === 'worker' ) {
            sessionStorage.setItem( 'token', e.data.session.token );
            return;
        }
    }
};

window.addEventListener( 'load', () => {
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open  = (method, url, async, user, password) => {
        App.__XMLHttpRequest(method, url, async, user, password);
        App.__webWorker.postMessage( '{{md5(session_id())}}' );
    };

    const worker = new SharedWorker( '{{$router->generate( 'web_notify_worker' )}}' );
    worker.port.onmessage = e => App.__onScriptComplete( e );
    App.__webWorker = worker.port;

    // The below gives me a Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation and the App.__webWorker.postMessage is executed
    let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open( 'GET', '/', true );
    req.send();

    // The below works fine but the App.__webWorker.postMessage is not executed
    fetch( '/', { method: 'GET' } );
} );
```

When I create a `new XMLHttpRequest()` this works fine and the `sessionStorage` item is set with the data. However, I do not use `XMLHttpRequest`, instead, I use `fetch()`. This seems to not create a `XMLHttpRequest` which I thought it would.

How can I execute a the `postMessage` function on my `App.__webWorker` every time a new `fetch()` is called? Preferably, after it is completed.

Update: This is my own framework, I used Smarty Template engine so ignore the `{{}}` prefixed areas. This is how I import data into the script from PHP.

Update: I have tried to do this, but I get `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Illegal invocation`:

```
var App = {
    ...,
    __fetch: fetch
}

fetch = ( uri, args ) => {
    App.__fetch( uri, args );
    App.__webWorker.postMessage( '{{md5( session_id() )}}' );
};
```

Comment: Something like https://github.com/werk85/fetch-intercept is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the override the global and call it. It would be a lot cleaner if you made it your own method and you call that instead of this 'hijacking

```js
const _fetch = window.fetch
// window.fetch = function() {
window.fetch = function(...args) {
  console.log('before fetch')
  // return Promise.resolve(_fetch.apply(window, arguments))
  return Promise.resolve(_fetch.apply(window, args))
    .then(resp => {
      console.log('inside then');
      return resp;
    })
}

fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
```

Comment: This is a lot more neat than my original solution! Your most recent edit works perfectly and achieves my exact aim! Thank-you so much!

Answer (score 1):

After some extensive Google searching, I figured out that the issue was storing the `fetch` in the `App` scope. To fix this, you have to store it within the `window` scope.

```
_fetch = fetch;

fetch = ( uri, args ) => {
    let f = _fetch( uri, args );
    App.__webWorker.postMessage( '{{md5( session_id() )}}' );
    return f;
};
```

This then works fine, every time a `fetch()` is sent, my `sharedWorker` is posted a message.

Comment: that is not true. you can store it in App, but instead of calling App._fetch(...args) you would need to call it like App._fetch.call(window, ...args)

Comment: You learn something new every day! Thank-you for the knowledge @Andrei